# Vagrant disk partition doesn't match Debian filesystem (partition is larger)

Tags: vagrant, debian, partitioning

I'm attempting to rebuild a development vm using the `debian/stretch64` box (i.e. Debian 9). I'm using Vagrant 2.0.2, with VirtualBox 5.2.6 on MacOS Sierra 10.12.6).

In my Vagrantfile I've specified a 30GB disk:

```
config.disksize.size = "30GB"
```

Virtual Media Manager (File menu in VirtualBox) shows the "virtual size" (capacity) of the stretch.vdi as 30GB. `VBoxManage showhdinfo "stretch.vdi"` also gives me the same information and indicates it's a `dynamic default` (i.e. resizable) disk, unlike .vmdk.

However, Debian reports a much smaller file system:

```
/dev/sda1       8.7G  8.7G     0 100% /
```

(it did have some space, but rsyncing a large shared folder on boot keeps filling it up).

Before it was full:

- I ran `sudo cfdisk /dev/sda` and found the volume was reporting 20.1G free space and only 8.7G on /dev/sda1.
- I also did `apt-get install lvm2` so I would have the tools with which to manage volumes.

I then used `fdisk` (not the curses version) to reconfigure the partitions (i.e. I deleted them all, made the first one 29G and added an extended 1G partition with the 'type' set to Linux swap).

Although I saw the message "Re-reading the partition table failed. Device or resource busy.", after a reboot the `cfdisk /dev/sda` output all looked correct:

```
    Device          Boot            Start         End     Sectors     Size    Id Type
>>  /dev/sda1                        2048    60819455    60817408      29G    83 Linux
    /dev/sda2                    60819456    62914559     2095104    1023M     5 Extended
    └─/dev/sda5                  60821504    62914559     2093056    1022M    82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Still however, `df` returns:

```
/dev/sda1       8.7G  8.7G     0 100% /
```

Various tutorials mention **pvcreate** and **pvresize**, however for the latter I get:

```
sudo pvresize /dev/sda
  Failed to find physical volume "/dev/sda".
  0 physical volume(s) resized / 0 physical volume(s) not resized
```

Here's my complete fdisk -l output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 30 GiB, 32212254720 bytes, 62914560 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe133a040

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           2048 60819455 60817408   29G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       60819456 62914559  2095104 1023M  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       60821504 62914559  2093056 1022M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

**What else should I be doing to get Debian to see the full 29G?**

Answer (score 0):

Fixed simply with:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
```

Now I have:

```
/dev/sda1        29G  8.7G   19G  32% /
```

Which I found [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10776/why-are-partition-size-and-df-output-different?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

(Have voted to close my own question).